# How to pass value from a sibling component to router outlet in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component

app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar>...router links here</app-navbar>
<app-controller>...contains multiple inputs</app-controller>
<router-outlet>... renders n pages </router-outlet>
```

How to use the dynamic data in `<controller>` component (which can change by user) in `<router-outlet>` child pages? The `controller component` builds the data which needs to be shared across all pages. Each page renders different form of tables based on controller component data.

I tried `eventEmitter` and `@input` `@outputs` but worked for parents and child not this hierarchy. using service also didn't work for dynamic data. I am not sure what is the benchmark for this kind of requirement.

to achieve this in angular.js I would include controller component into each page component and pass its data via `$rootScope` and add a `$rootScope.$watch` if I wanted to see they have changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can start using **subject** or Behavior **Subject** from RX js were you can update your data for multiple component at a single shot please find the few examples

```
// Behavior Subject

// a is a initial value. if there is a subscription 
// after this, it would get "a" value immediately
let bSubject = new BehaviorSubject("a"); 

bSubject.next("b");

bSubject.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log("Subscription got", value); // Subscription got b, 
                                          // ^ This would not happen 
                                          // for a generic observable 
                                          // or generic subject by default
});

bSubject.next("c"); // Subscription got c
bSubject.next("d"); // Subscription got d

// Regular Subject

let subject = new Subject(); 

subject.next("b");

subject.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log("Subscription got", value); // Subscription wont get 
                                          // anything at this point
});

subject.next("c"); // Subscription got c
subject.next("d"); // Subscription got d
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a service for this. Use it in all the pages that requires the shared data and provide it in the `app.component` so controller and the `render-outlet` will shared the same service instance.

In the app component:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  provide: [SharedDataService],
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

and in the children:

```
constructor(
  sharedDataService : SharedDataService,
) { }
```

This is how Angular recommends to handle communication between components.

Comment: controller had dynamic data. your code only shares static data.

Comment: You can exchange data using a `BehaviorSubject` in the service to send the data from the `controller` component to the one rendered in the `render-outlet`